# Custom loss wrong output size? *TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars*

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, loss-function

Hello I'm making my first custom loss and I get this error...

[image: Error]

Also I printed y_pred in case I get something useful and realized it had had shape=(32,19).

[image]

My rnn's output should be a 19-size array, so I am not sure what the 32 there represents. Shouldn't the loss function be passed a 19-size 1-dimension array for y_pred and y_true as well? Any tips welcome

```
def paperCustomLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    print(y_true,y_pred)
    loss = np.empty(len(icd_outputs[0]), dtype='double')
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        loss[i] -= y_true[i] * math.log(y_pred[i] + 1e-9)
        loss[i] -= (1 - y_true[i]) * math.log(1 - y_pred[i] + 1e-9)
    return loss

model.compile(
    loss=paperCustomLoss,
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy",
             #tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
            ],
    run_eagerly=True
)

h = model.fit(
    x=[input_ready_floats,input_ready_onehot,input_ready_icds],
    y=output_ready_icds,
    epochs=60,
    validation_split=testing_units,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[flexible_lr,
               csv_logger,
               #LossAndErrorPrintingCallback(),
               DifferencePrint(),
               EarlyStoppingAtMinLoss()
              ],
)
```

To answer a comment:

```
batch_size = 200
float_input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(timesteps,float_input_length),batch_size = batch_size,name="floats")
onehot_input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(timesteps,onehot_input_length),batch_size = batch_size,name="onehot")
icd_input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(timesteps,icd_input_length),batch_size = batch_size,name="icds")
merger = layers.concatenate([float_input_layer, onehot_input_layer, icd_input_layer])

hidden_layer_1 = layers.LSTM(units=150, batch_input_shape=(batch_size,timesteps,41) , activation="sigmoid", return_sequences=True)(merger)
hidden_layer_2 = layers.LSTM(150, activation="sigmoid", return_sequences=False)(hidden_layer_1)
output_layer = layers.Dense(icd_output_length, activation="sigmoid")(hidden_layer_2)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[float_input_layer, onehot_input_layer, icd_input_layer], outputs=output_layer, name="RNN for patient ICD prediction")
```

Comment: 32 is the batch size... what custom loss are u trying to replicate?

Comment: My batch size is define as 200.

Comment: your code doesn't say this... batch_size is defined in model.fit(...) if u don't specify it the default value is 32

Comment: I added the model code. I thought the batch size was determined there. The loss I am trying to replicate is from this paper "Long Short-Term Memory Recurrent Neural Networks for Multiple Diseases Risk Prediction by Leveraging Longitudinal Medical Records"

Comment: What shape of data should the function return?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it right in case anyone looks for this... what is passed to the loss is a batch of y_pred and y_true, so you need to calc the loss for every y_pred and return it, which means a return shape of (len(y_pred),len(y_pred)[0]). This works for my case at least, where the network output is a 19size array